# how to use display the value of an element of a list<string> in MVVM?

Tags: c#, string, mvvm, binding, listbox

Normally, when I binding de items source of a control in the view, the property in the view model use to be a list of an object. This Object has many properties and I can choose one of the to set the property DisplayMemberPath in the  control to show the information.

However, now I have a listbox and I want to display the path of the files that are dropped into the listbox, so the binding property in my view model is a list of string. However, in this case I can't see the itmes because I don't know what set in the display member path because he string object has not properties.

How can I show information in a control when the binding property in the view model is a simple type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are binding a `ListBox` to a collection of `String`s, you should not set the `DisplayMemberPath`. This will call the `ToString` method of the object that is bound (in this case `String.ToString()`) which just shows the text.

So just don't set `DisplayMemberPath` :)